# macOSにAnacondaをインストール後、condaコマンドが使えません

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

Condaが使えません。ターミナルで`conda`と実行すると以下のように出ます。

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

また、ターミナルで`which conda`と実行した結果は以下の通りです。

```
/usr/local/bin/conda
```

以下のリンク先に従ってPATHを通すということをやろうとしてみたのですが、
プログラミング初学者の私には知識不足でさっぱり分かりません。

[AnacondaのPATHの設定 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/funabashi800/items/c13c4f742f43d9ebdd86)

OSはmacOS Catalinaです。

どなたかお力をお貸しいただけると幸いです。
どうぞお願いいたします。

Comment: Anacondaはどうやってインストールしましたか?エラーには「pipやeasy_installでインストールしてもアプリケーションとしては使えません」とあります。

Comment: グラフィカルインストーラーをダウンロードしてインストールしました。その後、condaが使えなくなってしまったので、pip install condaでインストールしました。

Comment: pipからアンインストールしてみましょう。「使えなくなった」とはどういうことですか。たとえば、そのときなにかしましたか。

Comment: デフォルトのpython2からpython3にするためのコマンドを入力してからcondaが使えなくなってしまった気がします。(ですが肝心のデフォルトpython2をpython3に変更もできていません)

Comment: condaのアンインストールしようと試みたのですが、以下のようにエラーが出てしまいました...。「OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/conda-4.3.16-py2.7.egg/conda/fetch.py'」

Comment: 自分でも解決策を探してみたのですが、やはり分からなかったため、Macを初期化いたしました。質問に答えてくださった方、編集していただいた方、本当に有難うございました。